# OASDiff circular dependecy issue

Tags: rest, swagger, openapi

I'm currently using OASDiff to track changes in a Swagger REST API, and I've encountered an issue with circular dependencies in my JSON schema. Unfortunately, I can't modify the JSON schema to resolve these circular dependencies.

When running OASDiff, I receive the following error message:

```
Error: failed to load base spec from "FILENAME.json" with kin-openapi bug found: circular schema reference not handled - #/definitions/QuickSearchParameters -> #/definitions/FilterCriteria -> #/definitions/FilterCriteria -> #/definitions/FilterCriteria -> #/definitions/FilterCriteria -> #/definitions/FilterCriteria -> #/definitions/FilterCriteria
```

Is there any way to configure OASDiff to ignore this circular schema reference error and generate the output report anyway? I need to track API changes, and resolving the circular dependencies in the JSON schema is not currently an option.

Any help or guidance on how to work around this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

I have tried on the oasdiff UI as well but not getting output.
Here is the link : https://www.oasdiff.com/diff-calculator

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.